# Convert Nested queries into sql view

Tags: mysql, view

I have these three different queries.These queries gives me result independently correct.now i want to merge these three queries into single query or view to get result very easily from one query.

```
$sql1 = "select * from user_post_like  
                            inner join user_post 
                            on user_post_like.postID = user_post.postID 
                            where ((user_post.poster='$uID' AND user_post_like.userID!='$uID'  )  OR (user_post.wallID='$uID'
                                    AND user_post_like.userID!='$uID') 
                                    AND user_post_like.notificationStatus=0)";


    $sql2 = "select * from user_post_comment 
                            inner join user_post
                            on user_post_comment.postID = user_post.postID 
                            where ((user_post.poster='$uID' AND user_post_comment.commenter!='$uID') OR (user_post.wallID='$uID' AND user_post_comment.commenter!='$uID')
                            AND user_post_comment.notificationStatus=0)";


    $sql3 = "select * from user_post_share  
                            inner join user_post  
                            on user_post_share.postID = user_post.postID 
                            where ((user_post.poster='$uID'  
AND   user_post_share.Share_user_id!='$uID') OR (user_post.wallID='$uID' AND user_post_share.Share_user_id!='$uID')                                 AND  
user_post_share.notificationStatus=0)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your table structures and how you want the single result set to look.

If your three tables have the same structure, you can combine them with UNION:

```
$big_single_query = "$sql1 UNION $sql2 UNION $sql3";
```

If they don't have the same structure, you can combine the logic of the three separate queries into a three table join:

```
SELECT upl.*, upc.*, ups.* 
FROM user_post_like as upl
LEFT JOIN user_post_comment as upc on ...
LEFT JOIN user_post_share as ups on ...
WHERE (...) and (... ) and (...);
```

But since you didn't post the structures of your tables or the format of your output, you'll have to fill in the details to get what you want.

Comment: Then use the join syntax. Hopefully you won't need to use * as much as I did in the example - you're better off selecting just the columns you need for your program.